# cakePHP 1.3 missing controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

On cakePHP 1.3 I have a missing controller error for the URL www.example.com/about/

```
Error: AboutController could not be found.

Error: Create the class AboutController below in file: app/controllers/about_controller.php

<?php
class AboutController extends AppController {

var $name = 'About';
}
?>
```

I also know that the issue lies with the .htaccess, as the site was working until I accidentally deleted the .htaccess from /app/webroot/! Below is what I have currently as my .htaccess, but there must be something missing from it. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is it only for a single controller or same problem for all controller?

Comment: Download CakePHP framework folder from https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tags and replace the file you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name to "AboutsController" and the name = "Abouts".
Cake convention requires plurals for controllers.

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Basic-Principles-of-CakePHP/CakePHP-Conventions.html